# checking two lists contains same property values

Tags: c#

I have two lists as follow

```
var topicsA = new List<Topic>()
{
    new Topic(){ TopicCode = "T01", TopicAccessed = false },
    new Topic(){ TopicCode = "T02", TopicAccessed = false },
    new Topic(){ TopicCode = "T03", TopicAccessed = false }
};

var topicsB = new List<Topic>()
{
    new Topic(){ TopicCode = "T01"},
    new Topic(){ TopicCode = "T02"}
};
```

What is a quick way of setting the `TopicAccessed` value of `topicsA` to true where the property values of `TopicCode` are the same in topicsB

for example, in this case `T01`and `T02` would have `TopicAccessed` set to true

Regards

Comment: updated my answer with another solution with HashSet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All answers show quadratic algorithm complexity (Big O). This code snippet shows linear big O:

```
var accessedTopicsByCode = topicsB.ToDictionary(x => x.TopicCode);
foreach (var t in topicsA)
{
    if (accessedTopicsByCode.ContainsKey(t.TopicCode))
    {
        t.TopicAccessed = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a dictionary to have better performance:

```
var hash = new Dictionary<string,bool>();

foreach(var topicB in topicsB)
{
    hash[topicB.TopicCode] = true;
}

foreach(var topicA in topicsA)
{
    topicA.TopicAccessed = hash.ContainsKey(topicA.TopicCode);
}
```

The complexity of this solution is O(n+m) whereas nested loop is O(n*m). [ContainsKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4(v=vs.110).aspx)'s complexity is O(1)

Or you can also use a [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) because we only need the key, not the value:

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>();

foreach(var topicB in topicsB)
{
    hash.Add(topicB.TopicCode);
}

foreach(var topicA in topicsA)
{
        topicA.TopicAccessed = hash.Contains(topicA.TopicCode);
}
```

This has the same complexity as using a Dictionary, but it's more efficient in memory usage. [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx)' complexity is O(1)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
// We iterate though the items of topicsA list.
foreach(var topicA in topicsA)
{
    // If topicsB list contains any item with the same TopicCode like 
    // the current's item TopicCode, update the TopicAccessed.
    if(topicsB.Any(x=>x.TopicCode == topicaA.TopicCode))
    {
        topicA.TopicAccessed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is high complexity, op asked for a quick way.

Comment: It's an `O(n^2)` complexity. I don't claim that's the most efficient way to deal with this problem. On the other hand, I don't think that's a wrong answer that should be downvoted. Anyway, this is a personal point of view. Furthermore, since Jesus came with a better algorithm, I upvoted his answer and I suggested to the OP to accept his answer...